# Hibernate many-to-one tag attributes "insert/update"

Tags: hibernate

I am working with hibernate 3.0 and spring 3.x.
While configuring the relationship between two tables I came across two attributes.
The attributes of "insert/update" many-to-one tag.
Could anyone please explain what are these tags meant for.
Along with that if a small example also can be provided I would be grateful.

Regards,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7761) says:

> update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE and/or INSERT statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" association whose value is initialized from another property that maps to the same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.